# Send fake Return key key presses to QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to write some unittests for my QPlainTextEdit based widget, so I need to send fake key presses to it.

I can successfully send ordinary a-z key presses, but when I try to send a new line my keyPressEvent handler doesn't receive the key press.

In the code below the first sendEvent is working fine, but the second isn't. Where could the problem be?

```
for char in "import django":
    global_objects.app.sendEvent(editor, QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, ord(char), QtCore.Qt.NoModifier, char))
global_objects.app.sendEvent(editor, QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier))
```

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by me filtering the event else where in my code. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
global_objects.app.sendEvent(editor,
    QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return,
    QtCore.Qt.NoModifier, '\n'))
```

work? (Note the extra argument to `QtGui.QKeyEvent`.)

Comment: Thanks, but that does't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Putting word *"Return"* into the [QKeyEvent constructor's text](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7.old/qkeyevent.html#QKeyEvent) parameter should do the trick. Pls, check if this line would work for you:

```
QtCore.QCoreApplication.sendEvent(self.editor, 
                                  QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier, 'Return'))
```

hope this helps, regards